# Graphview, bar color every other

Tags: android, android-studio

sorry in advance it's my first post.
So what I would like to do is set different color every other bar .
What I've seen is that u can change color depending on y-value using

> setValueDependentColor

No idea how I should do this .

```
 BarGraphSeries<DataPoint> series;       //an Object of the PointsGraphSeries for plotting scatter graphs
    series= new BarGraphSeries<>(generateData());   //initializing/defining series to get the data from the method 'data()
    graph.addSeries(series);                   //adding the series to the GraphView
    series.setSpacing(0);

private DataPoint[] generateData() {
    mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getData();
    ArrayList<String> y_axis = new ArrayList<>();
    while(data.moveToNext()){
        //get the value from the database in column 1
        //then add it to the ArrayList
        y_axis.add(data.getString(1));
    }
    int n=y_axis.size();     //to find out the no. of data-

    Log.d("elements", String.valueOf(n));
    DataPoint[] values = new DataPoint[n];     //creating an object of type DataPoint[] of size 'n'
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        int x=i+1;
        DataPoint v = new DataPoint(x,Double.parseDouble(y_axis.get(i)));
        values[i] = v;
        Log.d("xypoints", String.valueOf(x));

    }
    return values;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please share some code with us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
series.setValueDependentColor(new ValueDependentColor<DataPoint>() {
        @Override
        public int get(DataPoint data) {
            int x,y,z;
            if(data.getX() % 2 ==0) {
                x=255;
                y=0;
                z=0;

            }
            else {
                x=0;
                y=0;
                z=255;
            }


            return Color.rgb(x, y,z );
        }
    });
```

I did this this wat but I didn't know you can create 2 graphseries. 
Here you can check how : [Link](http://www.android-graphview.org/legend/)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make the colour dependant on the actual values you can do it this way:

```
barGraphSeries.setValueDependentColor(new ValueDependentColor<DataPoint>() {
@Override
public int get(DataPoint data) {
return Color.rgb((int) data.getX()*255/2, (int) Math.abs(data.getY()*255/3), 100);
    }
});
```

the rgb() method takes values for each parameter between 0-255. You can set a specific colour by passing in specific values, or do something similar to the code above, where depending on your (x,y) points, the results will vary. The numbers chosen here are random but within the accepted scope of RGB values. Depending on the maximum values of X,Y you have, you should change the corresponding dividers from the ones I used (2, 3).

If you want to have a predetermined colour for each series, you can set it like so:

```
 barGraphSeries.setColor(255,0,0); //for red
```

here is an RGB calculator:
[RGB Colours](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_rgb.asp)

**EDIT**: added the following code as requested to paint every graph with an even X red and any with an odd X blue:

```
if(data.getX() % 2 ==0){
    barGraphSeries.setColor(255,0,0);
} else {
    barGraphSeries.setColor(0,0,255);
}
```

Comment: What i wanted to do is: examp: x=0 bar is red x = 1 bar is blue and every other.

Comment: @SebasTian you mean something like if (data.getX() == 0) {barGraphSeries.setColor(255,0,0); } ?

Comment: I meant like even and odd in different color.

Comment: @SebasTian if(data.getX() % 2 ==0) {barGraphSeries.setColor(255,0,0);} else {barGraphSeries.setColor(0,0,255);} This checks whether X is even and paints the series red, if not it paints it blue

Comment: Thank you very much my friend !

Comment: @SebasTian You're welcome. I'll add the code to my original answer so you can accept it!